# Get specific object from specific Id JSON

Tags: php, json

I have a little problem with my json file, what I am trying to do is get the specific object from my json file,  so in this json above when i add this parameter  **stream_id=** and for example i add this id **stream_id=200** it should show only the object with that id, so to be more clear it should show **id:200, name:Ravi Tamada, email:ravi@gmail.com** etc etc ,with PHP, thanks

```
{
        "contacts": [
            {
                    "id": "200",
                    "name": "Ravi Tamada",
                    "email": "ravi@gmail.com",
                    "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                    "gender" : "male",
                    "url": "http://149.202.196.143:8000/live/djemal/djemal/592.ts"
            },
            {
                    "id": "201",
                    "name": "Johnny Depp",
                    "email": "johnny_depp@gmail.com",
                    "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                    "gender" : "male",
                    "url":"http://149.202.196.143:8000/live/djemal/djemal/592.ts" 
            },
            {
                    "id": "202",
                    "name": "Leonardo Dicaprio",
                    "email": "leonardo_dicaprio@gmail.com",
                    "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                    "gender" : "male",


    "url":"http://149.202.196.143:8000/live/djemal/djemal/592.ts" 
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: @yBrodsky can you explain me with code please, this is my json so in php how to do that

Comment: Check [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could iterate through your JSON and look for the Id you need. Simple as that.

```php
$json = /* your json */;

$array = json_decode($json, true);

$result = getInfo(200, $array);

function getInfo($id, $array) {
    foreach($array AS $index => $element) {
        if($element['id'] == $id) {
            return $element;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes but that is only for id with the value 200, so if i change the id number in the url than it should return the result of that id, what if i wright channel_id=201

Comment: Well that's up to you to change that, you could just change the 200 to `$_GET['channel_id']`

Comment: i changed 200 to $_GET[ 'channel_id' ] and this error appeard  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'AS' (T_AS), expecting ';' in /srv/disk14/2280797/www/rido.sportsontheweb.net/webi/api.php on line 61

Comment: Oh, replace the `for` for a `foreach`

Comment: I made a PHPSandbox with the code you needed. There http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cfc31d03a1d196c22e87c15e41e27aaec2351cba

Comment: very nice, like it a lot, it works perfect, only need one more thing,  i shows like this              []string(189) "{"id":"200","name":"Ravi Tamada","email":"ravi@gmail.com","address":"xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country","gender":"male","url":"http:\/\/149.202.196.143:8000\/live\/djemal\/djemal\/592.ts"}"

Comment: and i want like this {"contact":[{"id":"200","name":"Ravi Tamada","email":"ravi@gmail.com","address":"xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country","gender":"male","url":"http:\/\/149.202.196.143:8000\/live\/djemal\/djemal\/592.ts"}]}"

Comment: Then simply add it to another array using `$newArray = array('contact' => $result)`, and then encode the array in JSON using `json_encode($newArray, true)`

Comment: this is my result when i add what you said    <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: result in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>39</b><br />
string(16) "{"contact":null}"

Comment: Well replace what the $result with what the function getInfo returns.

Comment: That sounds very time consuming to loop every time you need to get an item. Imagine a huge JSON. Wouldn't it at least be faster to index the array by ids on the first load and then get $array[$index]?

Comment: @Fanky Different problems, different needs. In a case where you need to access this data quickly, an object with the keys as the ids would be ideal. But if you only need to search for an id once, you don't need to do all the extra work to index the whole things. In the end, it comes down to what you need to accomplish.

Comment: I am very new to `PHP`, but this answer seems funny to me. How does scope work in `PHP`? Coming from `Java`, I use to creating functions that do not dependent on variables outside of the function's scope. You pass `$arrays,` which is fine, but then you call `$json`.  Could you not get a correct return using the passed `$id` and `array`?

Comment: @SedJ601 From what I can see, I simply choose my variable name poorly. The `json` variable inside the function is not the same as the one outside. The one inside the function is used to represent the current element of the `foreach` loop. This could be confusing, i'm going to edit the answer to make it clearer. Clearly this question is from a long time ago, when I was also kinda new to PHP. I find it really funny today. Thanks for bringing that to my attention.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use json_decode with $assoc=true (this option converts the json to an array, even to nested arrays) and then loop through the array to find the desired element.

Comment: it should depend on the value that is writen in the url, form example www.nice.com/api?channel_id=, it should show the result depending on the value that i give after =

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to loop through the JSON with a simple js/jquery function like below, where you just pass the specified id.

```
function getJsonById(id){
var json = {
        "contacts": [
            {
                    "id": "200",
                    "name": "Ravi Tamada",
                    "email": "ravi@gmail.com",
                    "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                    "gender" : "male",
                    "url": "http://149.202.196.143:8000/live/djemal/djemal/592.ts"
            },
            {
                    "id": "201",
                    "name": "Johnny Depp",
                    "email": "johnny_depp@gmail.com",
                    "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                    "gender" : "male",
                    "url":"http://149.202.196.143:8000/live/djemal/djemal/592.ts" 
            },
            {
                    "id": "202",
                    "name": "Leonardo Dicaprio",
                    "email": "leonardo_dicaprio@gmail.com",
                    "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                    "gender" : "male",


    "url":"http://149.202.196.143:8000/live/djemal/djemal/592.ts" 
            }
        ]
    };

var l= json['contacts'].length;
var c = 0;
while(c<l){
  if(json['contacts'][c]['id']==id){
    console.log(json['contacts'][c]);
     return json['contacts'][c];
  } 
  c++;
}
}
return "";
});
```

Comment: and in php, how can i do that

Comment: I apologize, I did not read the PHP part of this post. Don't know the PHP syntax off the top of my head, but you should be able to use the same logic. You could probably just copy and paste from the PHP documentation website.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to get the data by id more often and not loop through the array every time. So you can

```
foreach($users_array as $user_object){
    $users[$user_object->id]=$user_object;
}
```

and then access:

```
echo $users[202]->email;
```